# Fireworks CS5 & CS6 - Export as HTML ignores settings such as background repeat and page alignment

Tags: adobe-cs5, adobe-fireworks

I'm trying to export my prototype as HTML, but for some reason, the HTML setup settings are ignored. I've set a background image that needs to be repeated. Despite that, the background image isn't displayed at all. I've also set my page alignment to center, but the prototype gets aligned left regardless.

[image]

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same center alignment problems and came up with a [hacky workaround - blog post](http://borism.net/2012/03/23/how-to-centering-html-exports-in-fireworks/)

Note: Tested in Fireworks CS5 on Mac, but should work approximately the same in other versions or Windows.

Open /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Configuration/HTML Code/Dreamweaver/SLICES.XTT and locate the following line: (line 662)

```
WRITE_HTML("<!--Fireworks CS5 Dreamweaver CS5 target.  Created ", d, "-->\n");
```

Now add the following right below it:

```
WRITE_HTML("<style>body {text-align:center;}</style>\n");
```

and BAM! You’ve got centered exports.

Comment: Also confirmed working in Mountain Lion, Fireworks CS6.